# How to fix camera on me google maps android studio

Tags: android, google-maps

The question is posed in the topic, I had an attempt to implement this, but it turned out to be unsuccessful:

Here is an example of my code, I called it every second when I needed it, but because of this the map did not load the background

```
 public void myloc()
{
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        inCar = false;
        return;
    }
    fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {

            if (location != null) {

                    if(location.getLatitude() != oldLAN || location.getLongitude() != oldLON) {
                         oldLAN = location.getLatitude(); oldLON = location.getLongitude();
                        gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16.0f));
                    }
            }else { }
        }
    });
}
```

I need that when my geolocation changes, the camera
in Google Maps moved after me, as in navigator mode (this is not permanent, but optional).
Kind people tell me how to implement, and if not difficult, with an example.

Comment: I'd say you need to request location updates instead of continuously calling `getLastLocation()`. It will just keep returning the same location (or `null`) as the device does not automatically update its location, but some application (like yours) needs to request location updates.

Answer (score 1):

just simply call the moveCamera function.

```
gmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
```

animateCamera is used when zooming the Map automatically, Ex;

```
gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
```

Comment: That's exactly what the camera moves jerky, and I would like a smooth movement like that of "animateCamera", maybe there is still a tracking mode for a point like a navigator or another way to implement this without a timer.